# Two producers one surface

Tags: android, surface, producer

Ok this might seem like a simple question to some but I'm a bit lost and still learning.
So I'm learning to code on andriod and I'm learning some of the technical limitations.  Like 2 producers can't share the same surface.

I'm building a telestrator using FFMPEG.
I'm going to pull the frame from a video when pressing pause as such.

```
 int currentPosition = myVideoView.getCurrentPosition(); 

            Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever
                    .getFrameAtTime(currentPosition * 1000);
```

Now this will give me a bitmap to make a canvas on.

Now here is my issue that I'm kind of lost on.

My surface is playing the video, and is paused while grabbing the frame.  The surface can't have two producers is my understanding.  So how can I display the bitmap and draw on it using the paint/canvas function on the bitmap while the video remains paused and keeps position.

I know this is possible but I don't understand how it's done.

This is the last step to completing the project as I know how do put it all together on the FFMPEG once I have the position, the bitmap, and I know the canvas/paint.

Answer (score 0):

You could overlay the video surface with another one in which you would draw what you want.
You can achieve that by using a FrameLayout (you could use Relative or ConstraintLayout as well) with two childs, something like this:

```html
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
 
    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This way you would draw into ImageView and the videoView would not be affected.

Comment: ok just one question then, wouldn't the imageView then block the videoView?

Comment: It will appear on top of it. You can still handle user interaction and depending on what you're drawing into imageView videoView will still be visible.

Comment: yes what I did was set it to transparent in onCreate and then set the alpha to 255 opaque in the onclick.  But I'm having trouble getting it to all work together.  I made another post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883437/paint-on-video-frame  To show a bit more code and ask for some help in getting it to tie together because I keep crashing and I can't error check as the emulator won't play video and my phone is a pixel3 with the weird cord that doesn't attach to PC.   So I can't figure out where the error is.

Comment: Ok, i'll take a look. Have you set developer options and usb debugging on?

Comment: I don't have a cord for the phone.  I have a pixel 3. and the cord isn't USB friendly.  You have to have a special cord to do that.  I don't have one yet.  Google didn't exactly make it the most friendly phone to use.